# Using PHP to merge duplicate records from MySQL database in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0

I have a table that stores data that has been entered regarding the amount of waste put in a bin. So my table looks like this:

```
Material  |  Weight
===================
Paper     |  10
Plastic   |  5
Paper     |  7
```

As you can see, I'm going to have duplicate data in the table. At the moment I have multiple instances of different materials, and they all have different weight values attached to them.

Is it possible in PHP to get these duplicate entries, combine them in to one entry, and then display them? So the code would take the 10Kg of Paper and add it to the other instance of paper in the table (7Kg) and then output the value?

I have tried the `GROUP BY` in MySQL, but all that will do is combine all of the entries and give me the value of the top record, which isn't right.

Thanks!

Comment: Are your `Weight` values actually stored the way you've noted here? Posting your `DESCRIBE` output would help here.

Comment: I've changed the table to reflect how the data is stored. The weight value is always numerical, it doesn't contain the Kg suffix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use MySql, with a `SUM` column. This will sum up all values for that column, for each grouping. This is assuming the weight column is just a number (10 instead of 10kg).

```
SELECT 
    `material`, 
    SUM(`weight`) AS `weight` 
FROM `material_weights` 
GROUP BY `material`
```

If the weight column isn't just a number (10kg instead of 10), then there will be issues.

If all weights are in KG, then you should just remove the 'kg' value from each weight, and convert the weight column from text into a numeric column.

If there are different kinds of weights (KG, LB, G, etc), then the best way would be to have an extra field in the table, with the weight converted into KG.

Comment: I've had to change the way the site works, but this SQL works a treat. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since all your data seems to be in strings, it seems like you would be best served by using a php migration script to examine your data and then combine duplicates. First thing you want to do is determine which Materials have duplicates.

> SELECT Material FROM {TABLE} GROUP BY Material HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

From there you should loop through the materials that come back, and grab all rows with the Material value.

> SELECT * FROM {TABLE} WHERE Material = '{$material}';

This will give you all the rows labeled that Material. From there, apply any transformations (just in case there are values labeled g, for example) to the numeric value to ensure you're operating on the same type of value. Then you'd delete all the rows with that type of material. (You have a backup, right?)

> DELETE FROM {TABLE} WHERE Material = '{$material}';

Lastly, insert the value you just determined.

> INSERT INTO {TABLE} (Material, Weight), ('$material', '$weight');

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    material, 
    SUM(CAST(REPLACE(weight, 'kg', '') AS UNSIGNED)) AS weightsum
FROM
    tbl
GROUP BY
    material
```

You can use the `SUM()` function with `GROUP BY` to get the sum of the weight per unique material. In your case, your `weight` field appears to be a string. You can simply take out the 'kg' from each value using `REPLACE`, then convert it to an integer, which is then passed to `SUM()`.